# For purpose of EF linq query, is First(c=>cond) equiv to Where(c=>cond).First()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Is there any hidden subtlety, is one perferred, or is one just a shorter way to write the other?

```
Client = db.Clients.First(c=>c.Name == "Client 1")
```

and

```
Client = db.Clients.Where(c=>c.Name == "Client 1").First()
```

Comment: I would think they're equivalent; why not run SQL profiler and see what the SQL query looks like?

Comment: @Gabriel, the sql statements that get generated are identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are equiv.

Simple test it to add them to LINQPad and view the generated Sql statements and on my database I get the exact same Queries generated.

Update :

Below is example of the queries I get against my db.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'SKY02'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[MST_SQ], [t0].[EMP_EMPNO]
FROM [EMPLOYEE] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[EMP_EMPNO] = @p0
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'SKY02'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[MST_SQ], [t0].[EMP_EMPNO]
FROM [EMPLOYEE] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[EMP_EMPNO] = @p0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the first is preferred simply because it's shorter - so long as you're aware of what the argument is for. But yes, they should be equivalent - they're equivalent in the "LINQ model of the world" so to speak :)

The same "with a predicate" overload is present for various other LINQ operators - `Any`, `Count`, `Last` etc. Personally I keep forgetting about it, but it's worth remembering if you can :)

Comment: I not only forget about those, but then also misremember others that actually *don't* have such overloads (notably `Distinct()`.) For that, I'm grateful for MoreLINQ. :)